# Define constants in Util class or not

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns

Which is best?

I have a bunch of components in my projects. It's related to [Ashley](https://github.com/libgdx/ashley) (a java entity system) to libgdx (a game engine).

this components are like that:

```
public class SpriteComponent extends Component {

    private Sprite sprite;

    private SpriteComponent(Sprite sprite) {
        this.sprite = sprite;
    }

    public static SpriteComponent newInstance(Sprite sprite) {
        return new SpriteComponent(sprite);
    }

    public Sprite getSprite() {
        return sprite;
    }

}

public class PositionComponent extends Component {
    private Vector2 position = new Vector2();
    private float rotation;

    private PositionComponent() {
    }

    public static PositionComponent newInstance() {
        return new PositionComponent();
    }

    public Vector2 getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(Vector2 position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public float getRotation() {
        return rotation;
    }

    public void setRotation(float rotation) {
        this.rotation = rotation;
    }

    public void setPosition(float x, float y, float rotation) {
        position.x = x;
        position.y = y;
        this.rotation = rotation;
    }    
}
```

I have Entities that are compounded by these components.

Like:

```
Entity player = new Entity ();
player.add(SpriteComponent.newInstance(sprite));
player.add(PositionComponent.newInstance());
```

When we need to use these entities and components we do something like:

```
public class CameraPositionSystem extends EntitySystem {

    private ImmutableArray<Entity> entities;

    @Override
    public void addedToEngine(Engine engine) {
        entities = engine.getEntitiesFor(Family.all(PositionComponent.class, CameraFollowerComponent.class).get());
    }

    @Override
    public void update(float deltaTime) {
        for (Entity entity : entities) {
            /*get and use the component for that entity */
            final PositionComponent positionComponent = ComponentMapper.getFor(PositionComponent.class).get(entity);;
            final Vector2 position = positionComponent.getPosition();

        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I use a component I need to do this kind o calls: 
     ComponentMapper.getFor(PositionComponent.class).get(entity)

There are many calls like that so I decided to put this is an separated util class:

```
public class ComponentMappers {
    public static final ComponentMapper<CameraComponent> CAMERA = ComponentMapper.getFor(CameraComponent.class);
    public static final ComponentMapper<TouchDownInputComponent> TOUCH_DOWN_INPUT = ComponentMapper
            .getFor(TouchDownInputComponent.class);
    public static final ComponentMapper<PositionComponent> POSITION = ComponentMapper.getFor(PositionComponent.class);
    public static final ComponentMapper<BodyComponent> BODY = ComponentMapper.getFor(BodyComponent.class);
    public static final ComponentMapper<CameraFollowerComponent> CAMERA_FOLLOWER = ComponentMapper
            .getFor(CameraFollowerComponent.class);
    public static final ComponentMapper<SpriteComponent> SPRITE_COMPONENT = ComponentMapper
            .getFor(SpriteComponent.class);

}
```

All this explanation are to ask:

What is the best, use a util class like that or put each calls in they own respective classes. For example:

```
public class PositionComponent extends Component {
    public static final ComponentMapper<PositionComponent> POSITION = ComponentMapper.getFor(PositionComponent.class);

    private Vector2 position = new Vector2();
    private float rotation;

    private PositionComponent() {
    }

    public static PositionComponent newInstance() {
        return new PositionComponent();
    }

    public Vector2 getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(Vector2 position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public float getRotation() {
        return rotation;
    }

    public void setRotation(float rotation) {
        this.rotation = rotation;
    }

    public void setPosition(float x, float y, float rotation) {
        position.x = x;
        position.y = y;
        this.rotation = rotation;
    }
}
```

Or a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really is not a wrong answer to this. Different places in the Java libraries use different strategies. For example, the new Java 8 code uses `Collectors` with a bunch of utility methods, and the same is true for the `Arrays` and `Collections` utility classes. On the other hand, these require specific imports to make them happen.

In your case, since you have to import the `ComponentMapper` class anyway, it makes sense to make the utility constants part of that class, instead of a new utility `ComponentMappers` class. I see nothing wrong with:

```
ComponentMapper<PositionComponent> position = ComponentMapper.POSITION;
```

You already have the static methods on that class, why not make them constants: `ComponentMapper.getFor(PositionComponent.class)`?

As for the remainder of your code, your code is neat, the generics look clean, There's no need to add another level of abstraction.